# How to put a struct in a struct

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I just started using Matlab, and I absolutely despise (or not properly understand), the typesystem (or lack thereof).

Why does this not work ? I just want structs within structs (in a recursive function)

```
    K>> d = struct('op',1,'kids',[])

    d = 

          op: 1
        kids: []

    K>> d.kids(1) = struct('op',2)
    Conversion to double from struct is not possible.
```

I tried other things, like making `d=struct('op',1,'kids', struct([]))`, but nothing seems to work....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you index into it with `(1)`, you're trying to assign the struct in to the first element of `d.kids`, which is already a `double` array and thus a type mismatch. Just assign over the entire field.

```
d.kids = struct('op', 2);
```

To initialize it with a struct to start out with, do this, calling `struct` with no arguments instead of passing `[]` to it.

```
d = struct('op',1, 'kids',struct());
```

Don't give in to despair and hatred yet. The type system can handle what you want here; you're just making basic syntax mistakes. Have a read through the MATLAB  Getting Started guide, especially the "Matrices and Arrays" and "Programming" sections, found in the online help (call `doc()` from within Matlab) or [the MathWorks website](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/bqr_2pl.html).

Comment: Hey, thanks for this! How about if I want to have an array of structs for 'kids' ? I'm trying to simulate a binary tree, so a node has a label, and two subtrees, left and right.

Comment: Just assign in to it, without `()` indexing. Something like `d.kids = [d d];`. Seriously, go read the "Getting Started" guide, and work the examples. It'll cover this, e.g. in section MATLAB > Getting Started > Programming > Other Data Structures > Structures.

Comment: if you're trying to create a binary tree, try this:http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12339-datastructures or you could roll your own using Matlab's classes (look up 'classdef')

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an index on your second command.

```
d.kids = struct('op',2)
```

Your initial value `[]` don't make the field to be an array.

EDIT: Andrew's answer is clearer. I would add you can use the command `class` to ask Matlab about the type of an expression if you're unsure.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it in  a shorter way:

```
d.op = 1;
d.kids.op = 2;
```